# nested NSDictionary from plist

Tags: iphone, plist, nsdictionary

I have a plist, with main NSDictionary, in which its keys are dates.
For every date, I have a NSDictionary in which the keys are (let's say) categories.
Every Category holds Keys and values.

I would like to create 2 variables that each will hold the correct NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dates = ?
NSDictionary *Categories = ?
```

Below is my plist, please help to understand how this should be done.

**Note: I do know how to assign the first dates dictionary from the plist...
just stuck with the Categories.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.dates = dict;
[dict release];
```

The plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>2010-05-08</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Catergory1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>key1</key>
            <string>value1</string>
            <key>key2</key>
            <string>value2</string>
            <key>key3</key>
            <string>value3</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Catergory2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>key1</key>
            <string>value1</string>
            <key>key2</key>
            <string>value2</string>
            <key>key3</key>
            <string>value3</string>
        </dict>
    <key>2010-01-02</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Catergory1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>key1</key>
            <string>value1</string>
            <key>key2</key>
            <string>value2</string>
            <key>key3</key>
            <string>value3</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Catergory2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>key1</key>
            <string>value1</string>
            <key>key2</key>
            <string>value2</string>
            <key>key3</key>
            <string>value3</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've searched over the forum's history and found nothing that matches my scenario.

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should markup the values as arrays, so you can simply iterate over them.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>dates</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>date</key>
   <date>2010-05-17T12:40:32Z</date>
   <key>categories</key>
   <array>
    <dict>
     <key>key</key>
     <string>value</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
     <key>key</key>
     <string>value</string>
    </dict>
   </array>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>date</key>
   <date>2010-05-17T12:40:32Z</date>
   <key>categories</key>
   <array>
    <dict>
     <key>key</key>
     <string>value</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
     <key>key</key>
     <string>value</string>
    </dict>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
 for (NSDictionary *date in [dict valueForKey:@"dates"]) {
  NSArray *catgories = [date valueForKey:@"categories"];
 }
```

Comment: Hey, honestly, adding arrays just made it hard for me to read/understand,
let's go back to my plist for a sec,

i just want to have the following:
1 NSDictionary with all the dates
1 NSdictionary with all the Categories
then i could ask, [category objectForKey:@"Key1"] and i'll get Value1,

any ideas?

Comment: The problem is, that you have several "Category"-Dictionaries, and I think it could cause issues, if you mix them down to one Dictionary. On the other hand: What's the problem with `[catgories objectAtIndex:0]` in my suggestion?

Comment: Hey unset, i got your point, and you are right, 
i will use the [categories objectAtIndex:row] and will loop inside the main Dictionary.

Thanks for your help